# Multi-row equations aligned to the left in lyx

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to make a multi-row equation in LyX, but in order to do so, I have to center the equations (i.e. ctrl+shift+m), and I want them to be left-aligned.

I found answers about using `flalign`, but I don't know how to use LaTeX, only LyX, and I didn't find that option in LyX.

Comment: "I don't know how to use LaTeX, only LyX." Just to be clear, when you are using LyX, you are using LaTeX, actually. LyX is nothing but a program with a graphical user interface, just like TexStudio for example. LyX may look like a text-processing software but what it really is is just a kind of wizard to help you typeset using LaTeX commands. Just, contrary to TexStudio which basically lets you type the code, LyX acts as a friendly interface and will generate the code for you, depending on the instructions you give it.

Comment: What I meant is that I don't know LaTeX code, and I'd like to know how to make the multi-row equation using only LyX tools.

Comment: I cannot answer you about LyX, someone will. But I would certainly advise you to consider direct LaTeX typesetting. In the end you will find out that the ratio time spent / things obtained has been incredibly beneficial. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. I added the custom `fleqn` in document->preferences->document class.